Mock problem org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException
I'm just starting in spring test theory, but i do not understand how to use mock correctly
I have two basic classes
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String initialPage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/healthCheck")
    public String healthCheck() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        if (runtime != null) {
            try {
                long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
                long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
                long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
                return "freeMemory = " + freeMemory;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "OK";
    }
}

And test for it
@SpringBootTest
public class MainControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private Runtime runtime;
    @Mock
    MainController mainController;

    @Test
    public void testHealthCheck() throws Exception {
        // Create a mock Runtime object

        // Set up the behavior of the mock object
        when(runtime.maxMemory()).thenReturn(100L);
        when(runtime.totalMemory()).thenReturn(50L);
        when(runtime.freeMemory()).thenReturn(25L);

        // Replace the actual Runtime object with the mock object
//        Field runtimeField = MainController.class.getDeclaredField("runtime");
//        runtimeField.setAccessible(true);
//        runtimeField.set(MainController.class, runtimeMock);

        // Call the healthCheck method
        String result = mainController.healthCheck();

        // Assert the result
        assertEquals("freeMemory = 25", result);
    }
}

I have tryed to use @InjectMock and @MockBean, but that doesn't work.
What's my principal problem with mock, how should i use it correctly?

In your test, you created a @Mock for runtime but you haven't injected it anywhere.
In your controller code the Runtime instance is obtained by calling Runtime.getRuntime(). It's possible to mock returns from static methods but the syntax is a little different. See mocking static methods
Eg
when(runtime.maxMemory()).thenReturn(100L);
when(runtime.totalMemory()).thenReturn(50L);
when(runtime.freeMemory()).thenReturn(25L);
String result;
try (MockedStatic<Runtime> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class)) {
   mockedStatic.when(Runtime::getRuntime).thenReturn(runtime);
   result = mainController.healthCheck();
}
assertEquals("freeMemory = 25", result);


Error comes on the first line with when(...
II don't get how to fix that :(

inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

at com.example.demo.MainControllerTest.testHealthCheck(MainControllerTest.java:28)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)

There's ample information here in this answer to solve your problem. Time to read the information and think for yourself

When you use the @SpringBootTest annotation you are raising the full spring context, that is, @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) is used inside the annotation. In this case, you should use @Autowired on your controller and @MockBean on the classes whose behavior you want to override. On the other hand, you don’t need the whole spring context in this test and you can use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class), in this case you need to use the @InjectMocks and @Mock annotations, respectively, and the spring context will not be used, only those classes that you indicated in the class.
There is also a problem with Runtime - in order to override its behavior using a mock, you need it to be stored as a field in the controller, and you can pass it through the constructor.
here is an example implementation:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    private final Runtime runtime;

    public MainController(Runtime runtime) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String initialPage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/healthCheck")
    public String healthCheck() {
        if (runtime != null) {
            try {
                long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
                long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
                long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
                return "freeMemory = " + freeMemory;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "OK";
    }
}

In this case, you need to define the bean in the configuration class:
@Configuraion
public MyConfig {
   
    @Bean
    public Runtime runtime(){
        Runtime.getRuntime()
    }
}

Then do the test like this:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MainControllerTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    MainController mainController;

    @Mock
    private Runtime runtime;

    @Test
    public void testHealthCheck() throws Exception {
        // Create a mock Runtime object

        // Set up the behavior of the mock object
        when(runtime.maxMemory()).thenReturn(100L);
        when(runtime.totalMemory()).thenReturn(50L);
        when(runtime.freeMemory()).thenReturn(25L);

        // Replace the actual Runtime object with the mock object
//        Field runtimeField = MainController.class.getDeclaredField("runtime");
//        runtimeField.setAccessible(true);
//        runtimeField.set(MainController.class, runtimeMock);

        // Call the healthCheck method
        String result = mainController.healthCheck();

        // Assert the result
        assertEquals("freeMemory = 25", result);
    }
}


The answer was not obvious, Runtime.* methods are native, that's the reason why i couldn't mock them, so i did layer class and mock him instead.
@Component
@Getter
public class RuntimeWorker {
    private final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    private final long freeMemory;
    private final long maxMemory;

    public RuntimeWorker() {
        this.freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
        this.maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
    }
}

